# Why is `flags &= (ushort)~Mask;` problematic when `Mask` is `const`?

Tags: c#

The following code throws a compiler error CS0221: *Constant value '-2' cannot be converted to a 'ushort' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)*

```csharp
private ushort _fooFlags = 0;
public void SetFoo1Flag(bool foo)
{
    const ushort Foo1Mask = 0x0001;
    if (foo)
    {
        _fooFlags |= Foo1Mask;
    }
    else
    {
        _fooFlags &= (ushort)~Foo1Mask; // CS0221 error
    }
}
```

As the hint suggests, using `unchecked` fixes this issue.

```csharp
private ushort _fooFlags = 0;
public void SetFoo1Flag(bool foo)
{
    const ushort Foo1Mask = 0x0001;
    if (foo)
    {
        _fooFlags |= Foo1Mask;
    }
    else
    {
        unchecked
        {
            _fooFlags &= (ushort)~Foo1Mask;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm primarily a C coder, so I tried variations to see how these (basic) integer operations behave.

Removing `const` works fine..

```csharp
public void SetFoo2Flag(bool foo)
{
    ushort Foo2Mask = 0x0001;
    if (foo)
    {
        _fooFlags |= Foo2Mask;
    }
    else
    {
        _fooFlags &= (ushort)~Foo2Mask;
    }
}
```

..as well as replacing `const` with `readonly`.

```csharp
private readonly ushort Foo3Mask= 0x0004;
public void SetFoo3Flag(bool foo)
{
    if (foo)
    {
        _fooFlags |= Foo3Mask;
    }
    else
    {
        _fooFlags &= (ushort)~Foo3Mask;
    }
}
```

I'm using an explicit cast, so I'd expect `(ushort)~Foo1Mask` to become a `ushort`, regardless of what happens with `~Foo1Mask`.

What makes `const` so different, that it requires special treatment, while the other two (in my view) similar variations work as I have expected?

PS: I know in this example I could've used an enum and `[Flags]`.

Comment: It was actually suggesting `unchecked((ushort)~Foo1Mask)`, not an `unchecked` block.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks, I didn't notice that subtlety.

Comment: If you left off `const` or used `readonly` in a `checked` environment (like setting the project to used checked), it would also fail. It's just the `checked` is enabled by default for `const` values.

Comment: Since C# doesn't have `ushort` bitwise operators, perhaps using xor would be better than using `~`: `(ushort)(Foo1Mask ^ ushort.MaxValue)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` operator is supported for the following types: "`int`, `uint`, `long`, and `ulong`" as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#bitwise-complement-operator-).  There's an implicit conversion from `ushort` to all of those, but `int` is the "smallest" of those types, so it "wins" the fight and becomes the type of `~anyUshortExpression`.

An operation can also be performed at compile time when the expression involves entirely literals, constants, or other expressions that can be resolved at compile time.  This means that `~Foo1Mask` will be treated identically to the compiler as if you'd have written `-2`.  Which is why you see that in the compiler error you get.

As far as why you only see it when you use a constant, if you don't, then at compile time it has no idea that the `int` that you're trying to cast to a `ushort` won't fit inside of a `ushort`.  It can't know that until runtime when it actually tries to execute the cast (at which point it will throw in a checked context or wrap around in an unchecked context).  So it just takes your word for it at compile time, even in a checked context, since it has no other choice.